# Android SQLite database date is not the same as the system date?

Tags: android, sqlite

The time on the phone shows 11:40 am 4 July 2013, however, when trying to run

```
select datetime(); it shows 2013-07-03 23:40
```

I am running the sql query using app aSQLiteManager. It is 12hours difference. Is there any thing like set date() or set time() in SQLite? How do I fix this issue? I have app need to return a result from SQLite database based on the date and time.

Comment: In which timezone are you?

Answer (score 1):

Time zones. The internal clock is UTC, which you want here because it's canonical. The time displayed to the user is adjusted depending on the time zone you're in.

Comment: To see what you probably expected from your select statement, try `select datetime('now', 'localtime');`